# Using Array in a getElementById with a if statement for javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>

<a id="demo">Click me.</a>
<br/>
<a id="none">Click me.</a>


<script>
//trying to use linkArr to detect the 'id'

var linkArr = ["demo", "none"];
```

// wanna make use of an array in the function, have no knowlege of javascript beforehand. Im still learning.

```
var log = document.getElementById(linkArr[]);
log.onclick = inputChange;
```

//Im trying to use an if statement to carry out the function so i do not need to type the link over and over again.

```
function inputChange(e) {
if (log = "demo"){
window.open("http://www.cnn.com/");}
else if(log= "none"){
window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/");}
};


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

//Really Appreciate if anyone here can help me to hone my programming skills. (:

Comment: How to work with arrays should be part of any decent tutorial.

Comment: Instead of onclick handler, why can't you assign directly to href on <a> tag with target="_blank"?

Comment: i know how to use html, but im trying to learn how to add it in in javascript

Answer (score 0):

so a few things I noticed here

When you call `document.getElementById()` you need to pass in an actual value. So you're call should look like `document.getElementById(linkArr[0])` or `document.getElementById(linkArr[1])`

So if you are wanting to set onClick events for both of your elements, you could either use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < linkArr.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(linkArr[i]).onclick = inputChange;
}
```

or you could just do this approach:

```
<a id="demo" onclick="inputChange">Click me.</a>
<a id="none" onclick="inputChange">Click me.</a>
```

Finally, in your `onChange` function.. you do not need to reference `log`, because that element will be passed in for you when it is called.

```
function inputChange(e) {
  if (e.id == "demo"){
    window.open("http://www.cnn.com/");}
  else if(e.id == "none"){
    window.open("http://www.yahoo.com/");}
};
```

Comment: @AndrewL64 my answer shows examples of applying an `onClick` event to an element directly in the markup as well as in javascript. Not sure what you are saying.

Comment: The comment was an accidental copy-paste man lol I have deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to retrieve the anchor elements and then use the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to add a click listener to each anchor tag that will insert links to each element accordingly.

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
/* JavaScript */

var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".someDiv a");

anchors.forEach(function(anchor) {
  anchor.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(anchor.id == "demo") {
      window.open("https://www.cnn.com/");  
    } else if (anchor.id == "none") {
      window.open("https://www.yahoo.com/");
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="someDiv">
  <a id="demo">Click me.</a><br/><a id="none">Click me.</a>
</div>
```

You can use JavaScript ES6+ and a ternary operator to further shorten and simplify the above code like this:

```js
/* JavaScript */

var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".someDiv a");

anchors.forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.addEventListener("click", () => {
    window.open((anchor.id == "demo") ? "https://www.cnn.com/" : "https://www.yahoo.com/");
  });
})
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="someDiv">
  <a id="demo">Click me.</a><br/><a id="none">Click me.</a>
</div>
```

**N.B.** Do note that if you want to go with the ES6+ approach, you will need to use a JavaScript compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) to convert the ES6 code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript on production to support current and older browsers or environments.